# Postgres. Создать READ/WRITE таблицу на Slave машине (Replication)

Tags: sql, linux, ubuntu, postgresql

Здравствуйте!
Настроил реплику БД postgres по инструкции - https://www.8host.com/blog/replikaciya-baz-dannyx-postgresql-po-tipu-masterslave/

Теперь возникла необходимость создать на Slave машине в той же БД таблицу, в которую slave мог бы делать инсёрты.
Как это возможно? При попытке создать таблицу, получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR: cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction
```

P.S. На мастер сервер эта таблица не должна передаваться. Она нужна только локально на slave машине.

Comment: P.S. Передавать значения из этой таблицы на mster машину - не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming Replication задуманна как "бинарная". реплицируются изменения на всём кластере. всё, что попадает в WAL (вобщем-то всё кроме некоторых индексов и UNLOGGED table) попадает на реплику. чтобы такое стало возможным, рабы работают в `transaction_read_only` mode. Вы НЕ МОЖЕТЕ создать таблицу или положить туда данные.

обойти такой дизайн можно запустив ещё один кластер на славе параллельно. в другой `data_directory`. И связать реплицируемый slave с этим кластером через `dblink` или `fdw`.